# Java scheduling causing an error

Tags: java

This code is supposed to fetch the variables from my class Course.

```
    public void prettyPrint(){
        Course myCourse = new Course(myCourse.n, myCourse.days, myCourse.start, myCourse.end);


        for (int i=0; i>Courses.size();i++){
            System.out.println("---"+ Course.dayString + ' '+ ' '+" ---");
            System.out.println(myCourse.start +"-"+ myCourse.end+ ": " + myCourse.n );
        }
```

This gets me errors that say "myCourse.n may not be initalized." How do I initialize them if they are just pulling the info from the Course class?

Comment: What do you expect the argument values `myCourse.n` and others to be?

Comment: It's pulling information from a text file: myCourse.n is the name of the class, myCourse.days is when it meets, etc. That code was provided in the assignment.

Comment: Notice how your variable is also called `myCourse`. You're trying to access a field from a variable that hasn't been initialized yet. If this was the exact code in the assignment, you should go report it to your professor as wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I think you should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Answer (score 1):

`Course myCourse = new Course(myCourse.n, myCourse.days, myCourse.start, myCourse.end);` // **myCourse is just a reference, when you call new , myCourse hasn't been initialized.**

---

Maybe you should code like this:

```
Course myCourse = new Course(n, days, start, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference values in an object before creating it. However, you can create static class variables and reference them without creating any objects as shown:

```
class Course{
    static int n = 1;
    static int days = 180;
    //..other definitions
    //..
}

class Main{
    public static void main(){
      Course myCourse = new Course(Course.n, Course.days);
    }
}
```

However, static variables introduce dependency between instance variables. A better design would be the [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) with a sample implementation as follows:

```
class Course{
    int n;
    int days;
    // other instance definitions

    public course(int n, int days){
         this.n = n;
          this.days = days;
     }
}

class History extends Course{
     public History(){
          super(10,200);//the values that you want this course to have
     }
}

class Geography extends Course{
     public Geography(){
          super(20,100);//the values that you want this course to have
     }
}

class Main{
     public static void main(String args[]){
          Course history = new History();
          Course geography = new Geography();
     }
}
```